# Full width Carousel/Slider focused on center items

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I'm looking for a full width slider or carousel where the two items (li's) in the middle of the page are the 'main' ones, instead of it the left most item.

I know that probably doesn't make sense so I'll try a different explanation.

I've have a full page width slider with 10 images in a list that you can slide between let's say the browser width let's you see 5 at a time, and they scroll 1 by 1 when you click. If I resize the browser, I want the two or how ever many images in the main area of the site to stay still, and whatever is on the left or the right of this area to be visable but ignored, maybe even lowered in opacity.

Is this possible? Or does anyone know of a plugin that already does this?

Here's 2 images to make it clearer:

http://imgur.com/Y97Mb 
http://imgur.com/o5BTb

Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you ever find anything to put the first slide in the center of the carousel?

Comment: I didn't, sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Image links are broken unfortunately... :-(

Answer (score 1):

- **RoyalSlider** provides this functionality I believe, but costs $12.

  http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/visible-nearby/
- **CarouFredSel** appears amazingly flexible from the examples

  http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

  http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/45/ (some great examples)
- You may be able to use **jCarousel** (free), with a bit of styling applied.

  http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/